# Lambda for comparing two lists of map id fields for missing ids

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, stream

I have two lists of maps, and each map as an id field. I need to compare these two lists against one another to find missing ids from collectionB ("7777" in the below)

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> collectionA = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>() {{
        add(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{ put("id", "5555"); }});
        add(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{ put("id", "6666"); }});
        add(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{ put("id", "7777"); }});
        add(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{ put("id", "8888"); }});
    }};

    List<Map<String, Object>> collectionB = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>() {{
        add(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            add(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{ put("id", "5555"); }});
            add(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{ put("id", "6666"); }});
            add(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{ put("id", "8888"); }});
        }});
    }};
```

I am really looking to learn more about stream() so any help with this would be appreciated. As you can tell I am not really sure where to start with this:

I started going down this path but it seems like it is not the right approach.

```
    List<String> bids = collectionB.stream()
        .map(e -> e.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getKey().equals("id"))
            .map(x -> x.getValue().toString())
            .collect(joining("")
        )).filter(x -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I guess this gets me to two lists of strings I can compare but it seems like this isn't the optimal approach. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For starters, why are you using `e.entrySet().stream()` instead of `e.get("id")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter Map of items from `collectionA` which are not present in `collectionB`,  iterate `collectionA` and check for each entry is present in any of the `Map` in `collectionB`, and finally collect entry into `Map` which is not present in `collectionB`

```
List<Map<String,String>> results = collectionA.stream()
    .flatMap(map->map.entrySet().stream())
    .filter(entry->collectionB.stream().noneMatch(bMap->bMap.containsValue(entry.getValue())))
    .map(entry-> Collections.singletonMap(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me greatly. I am not quite certain why ); Collectors.toList(); works "outside"/past the semi-colon there. noneMatch is great I didn't know that was there.